# Como vectorizar operaciones con variables definidas dentro de un mutate

Tags: r, dplyr

estoy intentando generar un df en el que pueda realizar operaciones con las columnas de manera vectorizada, específicamente dentro de un mutate:

```
set.seed(1)

df = tibble(
  var1 = 1:10,
  var2 = rnorm(10),
  var3 = runif(10),
  var4 = sample.int(10)
)

df

# A tibble: 10 x 4
    var1    var2   var3  var4
   <int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
 1     1  0.377  0.294      6
 2     2  0.133  0.459      1
 3     3  0.804  0.332      3
 4     4 -0.0571 0.651      8
 5     5  0.504  0.258     10
 6     6  1.09   0.479      4
 7     7 -0.691  0.766      2
 8     8 -1.28   0.0842     7
 9     9  0.0467 0.875      9
10    10 -0.236  0.339      5
```

y cuento con los siguientes vectores:

```
vars_salida = c("x", "y")
vars_1 = c("var1", "var2")
vars_2 = c("var3", "var4")
```

Existe alguna manera de hacer ?

```
df %>% mutate(vars_salida = vars_1 + vars_2)
```

Claramente eso dará error, pero me gustaria saber si se puede hacer eso, ya que hacer:

```
df %>% mutate(x = var1 + var3, y = var2 + var4) # salida esperada

# A tibble: 10 x 6
    var1    var2   var3  var4     x     y
   <int>   <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1  0.377  0.294      6  1.29  6.38
 2     2  0.133  0.459      1  2.46  1.13
 3     3  0.804  0.332      3  3.33  3.80
 4     4 -0.0571 0.651      8  4.65  7.94
 5     5  0.504  0.258     10  5.26 10.5 
 6     6  1.09   0.479      4  6.48  5.09
 7     7 -0.691  0.766      2  7.77  1.31
 8     8 -1.28   0.0842     7  8.08  5.72
 9     9  0.0467 0.875      9  9.88  9.05
10    10 -0.236  0.339      5 10.3   4.76
```

es sencillo, pero realizarlo con mas variables seria muy eficiente, ya que reduce el código y disminuiría el error

Alguna idea de como hacerlo? me imagino que debe existir alguna notación que desconozco, como usar:

```
enquo(), get() o {{var}} :=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que se me ocurre, es muy básico, pero conceptualmente muy claro de entender: construir la sentencia dinámicamente y evaluarla luego:

```
Sentencia <- paste(
              "df %>% mutate(",
              paste(vars_salida, "=", vars_1, "+", vars_2, collapse = ", "),
              ")")

eval(rlang::parse_expr(Sentencia))
```

Es una solución rápida pero que se puede emplear en cualquier situación, incluso más complejas, construir una sentencia válida es todo lo que tenemos que hacer, y podemos verificarla antes de ejecutar, incluso no debería agregar mucho "overhead" por que en definitiva el trabajo pesado lo sigue haciendo `dplyr`. Lo que puede ser criticable es que de alguna manera "rompe" el flujo normal de un lote `dplyr`.

Otra forma más consistente con la plataforma `tidy` y con los métodos de evaluación no estándar que implementa, es construir directamente una lista de expresiones que `mutate()` puede llegar a evaluar:

```
lexpr <- setNames(as.list(paste( vars_1, "+", vars_2)), 
                          as.list(vars_salida)) %>% 
                    lapply(rlang::parse_expr) 

lexpr
$x
var1 + var3

$y
var2 + var4
```

Hemos construido una lista con dos elementos que son "expresiones", que aunque lo parezcan, no son cadenas comunes. Estas expresiones se pueden evaluar, además, el nombre de cada elemento es el nombre de la variable final. Ahora sí podemos hacer:

```
df %>% 
  mutate( !!! lexpr )
```

El operador "bang-bang" (`!!`) y su versión para listas `!!!` se implementaron justamente para resolver estos temas, la principal dificultad fue siempre como configurar el nombre de la variable final, estos operadores realizan una evaluación temprana, lo que hace `!!! lexpr` en definitiva es transformar todo en `x = var1 + var3, y = var2 + var4` y hacérselo llegar a `mutate()`

Comment: Increíble !! muy buenas las dos soluciones