# Crear una nueva columna con la diferencia de las filas en R

Tags: r, rstudio, dplyr

una gran consulta les escribo desde Perú, estoy haciendo graficas del covid-19 y me he complicado con un código en R, lo que deseo es crear otra columna con la diferencia de las filas , adjunto imagen de lo que quiero hacer, flecha verde - flecha azul = flecha roja y lo mismo quiero hacer con las demás variables de la 3:7 usando dplyr de preferencia, como podran ver me sale valores negativos y con un cero en la fila que cree CASOS_POS, agradezco de antemano su apoyo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aplique este código:

```
mutate(Casos_POS = -c(0,diff(Casos))
```

y funciono bien sin embargo quisiera colocar el valor arriba en la celda donde se ubica el cero , para que corresponda con la fecha adjunto imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener la diferencia puedes usar la función diff, agregándole un signo menos para obtener la diferencia de manera invertida en como trabaja esta función

```
df %>% mutate(Casos_POS = -c(0,diff(Casos)))
```

Tendrías que hacer esto para cada variable que vayas a crear con la diferenciación.

Si quieres generalizarlo, es decir, ejecutar eso para un conjunto de variables, te recomiendo ver [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/501853/como-vectorizar-operaciones-con-variables-definidas-dentro-de-un-mutate) pregunta

Comment: Muchas Gracias Bastian Andres lo acabo de probar y si funciona, hay forma de subir los valores una celda arriba para que vayan con la fecha correspondiente y asi poder hacer una grafica (adjunto imagen) . Saludos

Comment: Puedes invertirlo , dejando el ultimo valor como 0 df %>% mutate(Casos_POS = -c(diff(Casos),0))